# Rails 3.1 routing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a link to a record in my application:

```
<ul class="presentation-box">
  <% @presentations.each do |presentation| %>
   <li><%= link_to "Presentation", presentations_path(@presentation) %></li>
   <li><%= presentation.author %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

With the following line in the routes file:

```
resources :presentations
root :to => 'presentations#index'
```

For some reason, when I click the link it's taking me to the Presentation index view. I believe it should be taking me to the show view of the individual record?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `link_to` is incorrect.

`presentations_path` will actually point you to the `index`, you want `presentation_path(presentation)` to point directly to the resource.

Also, you can just do `<%= link_to 'Presentation', presentation %>` and Rails will build the correct path for you

Comment: With the shorter version is it possible to put the presentation record title in place of the word Presentation?

Comment: Yup, `<%= link_to @presentation.title, @presentation %>`.  The first argument is the text that will be displayed, the second will be the resource, which rails will convert to a path for you.

Comment: Hmm..undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass <-- when I use your last example code. Am I missing something out?

Comment: Oops, change `@presentation` to `presentation`, the parameter you're passing into your `each` block.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `presentation_path(presentation)`